# How to change the password of one datanode in cluster version of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: passwords, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Is it not possible to change the password in the Cluster Version 1.0 of Apache IoTDB?

I checked the official guide and other information, and it seems like I cannot only change password of one DataNode. Wonder if I can, and how I can change the password of one DataNode?

Answer (score 0):

In Cluster Version 1.0 of Apache IoTDB, after any datanode modifies the password, all datanodes will be using the new password, so you cannot change the password of one single datanode.